# How to make a tkz-tab red?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tkz-tab

I need this tkz-tab

```
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-tab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f\left(x\right)$ / 1}{$-\infty$ , $-\frac{b}{a}$ , $+\infty$}
        \tkzTabLine{ , \text{Opposé signe } a , z , \text{Signe de } a , }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to be red. The whole of it, text, lines, everything.

I can't find anything on this forum and I tried to put a `[color=red]` next to the commands but it only gave me an error.

PS: the text in the tab is in French but don't worry ;)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Page 11 of the documentation mentions `color` in combination with `colorT` (lines), `colorV` (variables), `colorC` (first column) and `colorL` (first line), these seem to be used in `tkzTabInit`. Finally, page 26 mentions `node style/.append style` which would probably allow to set the text color inside the nodes.

Comment: @PhilippImhof you are right but if Romain want everything in red ... `\color{red}` . A good thing is to put all this code in a group to continue in black !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-tab,amsmath}

\begin{document} 
  \begingroup
    \color{red}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f\left(x\right)$ / 1}{$-\infty$ , $-\frac{b}{a}$ , $+\infty$}
      \tkzTabLine{ , \text{Opposé signe } a , z , \text{Signe de } a , }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \endgroup

  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $f\left(x\right)$ / 1}{$-\infty$ , $-\frac{b}{a}$ , $+\infty$}
      \tkzTabLine{ , \text{Opposé signe } a , z , \text{Signe de } a , }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, love it! I had found something but it wasn't that good and your solution is perfect!

Comment: Actually I tried it and it doesn't work. The only thing that differs between your code and mine is the document class. I'm in a report. Does that change everything?

Comment: @Romain no it's not important here. Can you put your full code in the question?

Comment: Shit sorry for that last comment. I made a mistake and your solution actually works. Sorry again